# dynamically adding validators

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my case I would like to dynamically add validators to my control based on given logic. For each control I first check something in my DB and if it goes aout that field is required I would like to add requiredField to that control. I firt iterate through each control and if its required I add attribute required="true".

I added this code but it doens work I mean nothing happens, none validation is being made.

```
if(gc.Attributes["controlid"] != null)
    {
        RequiredFieldValidator validator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        validator.ControlToValidate = gc.Attributes["controlid"];
        validator.ErrorMessage = gc.Attributes["errormessage"];
        this.Controls.Add(validator);
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Where are you adding the validators to the page?

Comment: on PageLoad, all are in the updatePanel

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add it to the Page's validators collection in order for the server side validation to occur.  Adding it just to the page controls collection as you did is what is needed to get the JavaScript validation to get rendered to the browser.

```
Page.Validators.Add(validator);
```

Comment: Are you making sure to run your code above and re-create the controls on postback?

Comment: yes it is every time poastback goes and page_load event fires

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding your Validator control to the same container as the control it validates? Validator controls require the target control to be in the same INamingContainer.